# constructor chaining with interface as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

inside my winform class I have  constructor

```
private IBookRepository _Repository;
        public AddEditForm(IBookRepository repository )
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Repository = repository;
        }
```

now I want to use constructor chaining but somewhere I made it wrong. I tried with

```
public AddEditForm(Book book) : this(IBookRepository repository)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're adding another constructor, you want something like:

```
public AddEditForm(Book book, IBookRepository repository) : this(repository)
{
   ...
}
```

when chaining constructors using `this`, you pass parameters to another constructor which are declared in the calling constructor's parameter list.

Answer (score 3):

To pass the repository to your chained constructor you have to accept it as a parameter on your first constructor like this:

```
public AddEditForm(IBookRepository repository, Book book) : this(repository)
{
   // here you can use both book and repository
}
```

If possible, you could also construct the repository directly like this:

```
public AddEditForm(Book book) : this(new BookRepository())
{
   // here you can only use book 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass IBookRepository in as a parameter to your constructor. Below is an example.

```
public AddEditForm(IBookRepository repository, Book book) : this(repository)
{
   // your code here
}
```

**This code assumes you have another constructor that takes a type `IBookRepository`**

```
public AddEditForm(IBookRepository repository)
{
   // your code here
}
```